# Puppet - Apply array to resource

Tags: arrays, resources, puppet

Consider the following snippet :

```
define custom::line_mgmt ($file, $line) {
    exec { "/bin/echo '${line}' >> '${file}'" }
}
```

When the `custom::line_mgmt` is used to insert a single pattern, it works as expected :

```
$demovar = "TEST1"
custom::line_mgmt {
    file => "/tmp/test",
    line => $demovar,
}
```

But if I want to insert multiple patterns from an array such as :

```
$demoarray = [ "TEST1", "TEST2" ]
custom::line_mgmt {
    file => "/tmp/test",
    line => $demoarray,
}
```

It treats the array as a whole and tries to insert `TEST1TEST2` and not `TEST1` and then `TEST2` in 2 different iterations.

Can somebody point me to my mistake ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `$line` parameter assumes an array value that is used in the string expression `"/bin/echo '${line}' >> '${file}'"`.

In Puppet, arrays are coerced into Strings by concatenating all their elements.

Puppet (with the pre-puppet4 parser, i.e. `future_parser=false` in Puppet `3.2` or later) will only "iterate" through an array when it is used for a resource title.

```
custom::line_worker($file) {
  exec { "/bin/echo '${title}' >> '${file}'" }
}
define custom::line_mgmt ($file, $line) {
  custom::line_worker { $line: file => $file }
}
```

Note that this crashes and burns when you want to add similar lines to different files (because the `worker` resources will have the same title, which is forbidden). There are ways around that, but those are likely too much hassle for this task.

Note that for this particular task, you can employ the `file_line` type from the [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/) module.

It may also be worthwile to consider [templates](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html#iteration) to do your iteration footwork, or even employ a [concat](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat) module to manage the whole file piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

From puppet-3.2 you can use `each` type. Here I give an example that will let you add values from an array of strings to files that are given in another array. You can specify just one file, that should work as well. I am using `file_line` type from puppet stdlib.

```
class testmodule::test {

   define linemgmt( $file, $line ) {
     file_line { "$file_$line" :
        path => $file,
        line => $line,
     }
   }

  $demoarr = [ "test", "test2" ]
  $demofiles = [ "file1", "file2" ]

  each($demoarr) | $index, $value | {
    linemgmt { "test_$index" :
      file => $demofiles[$index],
      line => $value,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the solution with each above works, however that is only if the future parser was enabled in puppet.conf or passed as an option to puppet apply, each is part of not released yet Puppet 4.x